# 409: conflict error while copying Artifacts in Artifactory using REST API

Tags: powershell, artifactory, http-status-code-409

I am trying to make a copy of an artifact in the same repository in Artifactory from PowerShell. Below is the code I am using to achieve this. And I am getting 
`"Invoke-RestMethod: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict."` error when I execute this code.

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri

"http://server/artifactory/api/copy/repoName/Package1.nupkg?to=/repoName/Package2.nupkg" -Method POST -UseDefaultCredentials

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use PUT method . POST is used to create. PUT is used to create or update.

Comment: Thanks Manmohan! I tried using PUT instead of POST and getting "Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed." error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out besides just retrying?  It always works when I retry.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when trying to use folders.
If that's your case too, try PUT-ing the folder path first, and make sure to authenticate the call both for this and for POST-ing the copy:

```
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$user:$apikey"));

# Create path first
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://server/artifactory/targetRepo/targetPath" `
    -Method PUT `
    -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = "Basic $($token)"}

# Copy item
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://server/artifactory/api/copy/repoName/path/Package1.nupkg?to=/targetRepo/targetPath/Package2.nupkg" `
    -Method POST `
    -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = "Basic $($token)"}
```

Comment: it makes it worse. it creates a zero-size artifact "targetPath" not a folder

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I encountered this error when I tried copying an artifact to a destination that already exists (Basically, replacing an artifact by the exact same name with another copy).  My user did not have delete privileges for the repo. The exact error text was:

```
  "messages" : [ {
    "level" : "ERROR",
    "message" : "User doesn't have permissions to override <artifact-name>. Needs delete permissions."
  } ]
```